# plugin compile with make would not compile module

Tags: pyqgis, ubuntu, assertionerror

Ubuntu 14.04
QGIS 2.6
PyQt4

I'm following one of many tutorials on 'plugin builder', here is the latest one I'm trying with: http://www.digital-geography.com/build-qgis-plugin/

It all seems very straightforward. I run 'make'...
make
pyrcc4 -o resources_rc.py  resources.qrc

A new file: 'resources_rc.py' is added to the plugin folder. Nothing else.

On loading the plugin through QGIS nothing happens except a 'No messages." message at the bottom-right of the screen.

It seems 'make' is not compiling the modules. Even after making changes to a dialog with Qt Designer.... and running 'make' again, it ignores the changes to the ui files. On running 'make' again I get:
make: Nothing to be done for 'default'.

I wish not to mislead.. but I notice the 'test_plugin_dialog_base.py' (I assume this is the default dialog created by plugin builder) has no corresponding .py file; I can see test_plugin_dialog.py and test_plugin_dialog.pyc; are they the compiled (py and bytecode) ui?

Assuming that 'make' somewhat doesn't work, I run:
pyuic4 -o test_plugin_dialog_base.py test_plugin_dialog_base.ui

A new file is created: 'test_plugin_dialog_base.py'

I run 'make' again for good measure...
make: Nothing to be done for 'default'.

On loading the plugin in QGIS I get the same 'No messages.' message at the botton-right for a couple of seconds before disappearing. The plugin is visible and ticked in the plugins manager put not loaded.

Am I doing something wrong?

'make test' returns the following

```
********************************************
********************************************
----------------------
Regression Test Suite
----------------------
nose.plugins.cover: ERROR: Coverage not available: unable to import coverage module
QGraphicsScene::addItem: item has already been added to this scene
#1 Test that the plugin __init__ will validate on plugins.qgis.org. ... ok
#2 Test we can click cancel. ... ok
#3 Test we can click OK. ... ok
#4 Test that QGIS properly parses a wkt string. ... Loading a style file that was saved with an older version of qgis (saved in 1.9.0-Master, loaded in 2.6.1-Brighton). Problems may occur.
ok
#5 QGIS environment has the expected providers ... ok
#6 Test we can click OK. ... ok
#7 Test that translations work. ... FAIL

======================================================================
FAIL: Test that translations work.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/xxxxxx/.qgis2/python/plugins/TestPlugin/test/test_translations.py", line 49, in test_qgis_translations
    self.assertEqual(real_message, expected_message)
AssertionError: u'Good morning' != 'Goeie more'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 7 tests in 0.143s

FAILED (failures=1)
----------------------
If you get a 'no module named qgis.core error, try sourcing
the helper script we have provided first then run make test.
e.g. source run-env-linux.sh <path to qgis install>; make test
----------------------
********************************************
********************************************
```

Apart from the 'Translation error' the rest seem to work ok. Except it doesn't.

Comment: I am now able to answer my own question but lack reputation to do that.

Comment: I can't find a clear pattern but it seem that sometimes uninstall/install/reinstall the plugin is not enough. Restarting QGIS does the job! There is nothing wrong with the way 'make' behaves the way I explained. Also, no 'make' is necessary for cosmetics changes to forms. Of course, functionality changes to "any part" of the code requires 'make'.

Comment: "Questions about software development are off-topic here unless they relate directly to Geographical Information Systems". How does a question about QGIS plugin development not fit that criteria?

Comment: who can reopen this question? I suppose the answer is not related to programming but to using `make`.

Comment: I would send the OP to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4219255, and I would suggest the maintainers of the plugin builder add the `.PHONY` rule to it.